# Microsoft Azure SSIS: Excel (taskfactory) Error

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, taskfactory

I get this error when I execute my SSIS package in Azure. I was wondering if anyone has experience with TaskFactory - Excel connection with new SSIS shifted to Azure datafactory. Thanks

> {    "SsisDBOperationGuid": "",
>       "SsisDBOperationId": 9,
>       "OperationErrorMessages": "11/25/2019 9:16:50 PM +00:00 : Import Excel into EDW table:Error: TF Excel Source failed validation and
>   returned error code 0xC004800B.\r\n\n11/25/2019 9:16:50 PM +00:00 :
>   Import Excel into EDW table:Error: One or more component failed
>   validation.\r\n\n11/25/2019 9:16:50 PM +00:00 : Import Excel into EDW
>   table:Error: There were errors during task validation.\r\n\n",
>       "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "factSSIS (West US)",
>       "executionDuration": 15,
>       "durationInQueue": {
>           "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
>       } }

Comment: Please add some more information if you think can help, like any background on your SSIS package etc.

Comment: Hello,

This SSIS package pulls from an SFTP then uploads the file from thatSFTP location and stores it on one of our production servers in a shared file folder. The SSIS package then takes that file that was uploaded to the shared folder and uploads it into a production database on azure.

The error when I execute the SSIS package comes from the SFTP connection and the excel file connection(TaskFactory) giving this error below:

Comment: MonsciergeProductionImport:Error: The connection type \"SFTPConnection\" specified for connection manager \"SFTP\" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type. This error is returned when an attempt is made to create a connection manager for an unknown connection type. ProductionImport:Error: The connection type \"ExcelConnectionTF\" specified for connection manager \"TF Excel Connection\" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type. This error is returned when an attempt is made to create a connection manager for an unknown connection type

Comment: Please edit the question itself and provide details there with correct formatting. this will be easier to read and understand